# Passing a string parameter within a lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-2019

I have below two functions:

```
public static void ExecuteMethod(Action myMethod, string methodName)
{
    ExecuteMethod(() => { myMethod(); return true; }); // how to pass as paramter methodName here?
}

public static object ExecuteMethod(Func<object> myMethod, string methodName)
{
    MyLog.Write("Calling to " + methodName);

    // execute passed method
    myMethod();

    // more stuff here
}
```

In the first method ExecuteMethod how can I pass the parameter methodName within the lambda:

```
ExecuteMethod(() => { myMethod(); return true; });
```

Comment: Did you already try `ExecuteMethod(() => { myMethod(); return true; }, methodName);`?

Comment: What is wrong with `ExecuteMethod(() => { myMethod(); return true; }, methodName);`? Why do you want to pass `methodName` *within* the lambda (whatever that means)?

Comment: @SomeBody just what i was looking for. thanks

Comment: @Sweeper i need to print method name for logging

Comment: @Ralph how about using `[CallerMemberName]` would this not be enough ?

Comment: @Franck because it takes the name of the main method where the call using the lambda is done instead of taking the name of myMethod()